# KendoUI grid create : how to deal when server response only the id of the new created item

Tags: telerik

I want to use the KendoUI grid widget with a rest API (manage by dreamfactory); when i create a new item with the grid the server response contains only the new id and NOT the fully new item (aka all the fields) as I read in this forum http://www.telerik.com/forums/request-for-support-on-editable-grid#2098471.

"When you add a new item in the Grid its ID should be generated on the server and the newly inserted item (as an array) back to the client. This way the DataSource can update its internal data and the Grid widget will update the column for this field. In case the server does not return the result, the inserted item will be treated as a new one every time you sync the dataSource. The same applies for destroy and update functionality."

My question is how to deal with if we cannot modify the contains of the server response.

here is the response i get from the server : {"record":[{"id":26}]}

Any idea?

Comment: after read again the dreamfactory docs, i found my solution; i just add field=* to my rest url and the server response return the full new item;

Answer (score 0):

According to [the DreamFactory documentation](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/Database-Creating-Records), only the id of the created record is returned by default. [The docs also mention that you may select the returned fields](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/Database-Records#selecting-returned-fields). Using `fields=*` will return all created fields. You should be sure to use [the `record` wrapper](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/Database-Creating-Records#multiple-records) to force the return of an array rather than a single, unwrapped id field.